# How to use Lettering.js with Drupal 7 on site name?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, drupal

I am trying to use Lettering.js on the site name of my new Drupal 7 website. Here is what I have done so far:

1. I downloaded the file from Github and put it in a folder called scripts inside my theme. (so it looks like this /sites/all/themes/MyThemeName/scripts/jquery.lettering.js)
2. Then I added the script to my theme's info file using this syntax "scripts[] = scripts/jquery.lettering.js". I can see that the script is being loaded when I view the page source.

The part I'm having problems with is how to call it. I've been reading the documentation at http://drupal.org/node/171213 but I'm still confused. I assume that I should put the call in the template.php and that I can use $site_name to get access to the site name within the site but I'm unsure where to go from there.

Thanks to anyone who can offer some advice.

Answer (score 1):

All what lettering.js does is to split a text into spans.

```
<p>Hey</p>
```

Becomes

```
<p><span class="char1">H</span><span class="char2">e</span><span class="char3">y</span></p>
```

See the source code for details: https://github.com/davatron5000/Lettering.js/blob/master/jquery.lettering.js

This can easily done with a preprocess function or in your template using PHP:

```
$chars = str_split($site_name);
$letter_site_name = "";
for($i=0,$count=count($chars);$i<$count;$i++) {
   $letter_site_name = '<span class="char' . ($i+1) . '">' . $chars[$i] . '</span>';
}
```

If you want to use lettering.js anyway you have to write an additional javascript.
This script has to define a Drupal behaviour which might run letteringjs on all headlines with the class lettering.

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.headline_lettering = {
    attach:function (context, settings) {
      $("h1.lettering:not(.lettering-attached)", context)
         .addClass('lettering-attached')
         .lettering();
    }
  }
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the previous answer.

The javascript can be added using drupal_add_js() in template.php:

```
drupal_add_js($path_to_theme . '/scripts/jquery.lettering-0.6.1.min.js');
```

And the additional script mentioned above can be added to page.tpl.php as

```
<script>
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.headline_lettering = {
    attach:function (context, settings) {
      $(".lettering:not(.lettering-attached)", context)
         .addClass('lettering-attached')
         .lettering();
    }
  }
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

I did not add the .h1 in the script and then I just need to add a class "lettering" to any text and the lettering will be applied.

Then you can use [Kern.js](http://www.kernjs.com/) to adjust the position of each letter. It produces CSS that needs to be included on the page.